# How to find and replace in current line(coming from fgets())? Php

Tags: php, fopen, fgets, fwrite

I am trying to change a .js file using PHP.
I am able to get the content of file line by line using `fgets()` but I am unable to replace in the string that is currently coming from `fgets()`.

I have tried using `fputs($handle, $read_line)`, but it gives some weird results.

File data

New data line 1

New data line aaa 2

New data line 3

Below is my PHP code to replace "aaa" with "abc".

```php
$file_path = $dir.'test\folder\folder2\file.js';

if($handle = fopen($file_path, 'r+')) {

    while(!feof($handle)) {
        $read_line = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($read_line, 'aaa')){
            $read_line = str_replace("aaa","abc",$read_line);
        }
        fputs($handle, $read_line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The expected result should be

New data line 1

New data line abc 2

New data line 3

But output is

New data line 1

New data line 1

a

a

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `strpos` will return 0 if the search string is found from the first character. So use the `!==` operator to distinguish between an `strpos` error, and a match from the zeroth character.

```
if(false !== strpos($read_line, 'aaa')){
     $read_line = str_replace("aaa","abc",$read_line);
}
```